# Transition in navbar "jumping up" before animation starts

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Hello there I am trying to animate the navbar items when one of them is clicked. The idea is that if an item gets clicked it slides down like 15px.

[image: initial]

[image: clicked]

Here is what I have done:

.jsx:

```
<div className="navbar">
   <h2 onClick={setPersonal} className={page===1 ? "clicked":""} >Personal</h2>           
   <h2 onClick={setResume} className={page===2 ? "clicked":""} >Resume                       
   <h2 onClick={setContacts} className={page===3 ? "clicked":""} >Contact me</h2>
</div>
```

.css:

```
.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:  space-between;
  align-items: start;
  padding-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  margin-top: 21px;
}

.navbar h2{
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar h2.clicked {
  transform: translateY(15px);
  line-height: 90%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
```

Problem is when I click one item, it jumps up before transitioning down as you can see in the image below with Resume.
[image]

This only happens when animating I don't understand why.

Comment: why are you changing the line-height?

Comment: @TemaniAfif hm initially i wanted a small border underneath when clicked. But I now see that was the problem. Thank you a lot!

Comment: FYI: That's really _terrible_ coding, for a navigation. Why are these items h2 headlines, and why is there no _actual_ link in there anywhere? The usability of this will likely be very bad, especially for people using assistive technologies.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your feedback. If you could expand on why the usability is bad would be great for me. There is no link because I am using React's conditional rendering instead of linkng into a different page. Does that make sense?

Comment: Users who use their keyboard for navigation instead of a pointer device, will likely not be able to "tab" to those pseudo buttons, without further additions (tabindex attribute) they will probably not be able to use them at all. And I won't be able to open such a "link" in a new tab either. (The latter is probably not relevant from the point of anyone developing an SPA - but too many sites these days _needlessly are_ SPAs IMHO, and being able to open content in a new tab would often _increase_ their usability in my eyes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is line-height being set to 90% only after the click!

I should have placed the line in the .navbar h2{}